# Is there a way to zoom on the Emoji keyboard of Windows

Tags: windows-10, emoji-keyboard

The Emoji-Keyboard (feature added in 2019) of Windows can be obtained by the shortcut `Win + '.'` .

The pop-up that appears has a a static size, and in most of the use cases, is very small (hard to distinguish the details of each icon).

Is there a way to change it's size ? (like definitely)